# How to change the data grid view column width?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to change the column's widths in my data grid view.
The data for the columns are obtained from a database.

I've tried the follow code with no luck.
(Using Visual Studio 2017)

```
private void dvgVacancySkill_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewColumn VacancyID = dvgVacancySkill.Columns[0];
    VacancyID.Width = 50;
}
```

[I want to change the column width of "VacancyID"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZkDe.png)

Comment: could you check the MinimumWidth property on the VacancyID column? As per the remarks given in the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width(v=vs.110).aspx), "If the specified value when setting the Width property is less than the value of the MinimumWidth property, the MinimumWidth property value is used instead."

Answer (score 0):

Nick
use this code, where you declare the column

```
Datagridview1.Columns["ColumnName"].Width = 100;
```